# How to make addition of two polynomials have no integer root.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Consider I have two degree $d$ polynomials $f_1$ and $f_2$, and they do not have any root in common. I need to compute $f_3=f_1+f_2$, but $f_3$ may have some roots in $R$. So I pick two random polynomials, $r_1,r_2$ of degree $d$, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ have no roots in common in $R$. Then I compute $f'_3=r_1\cdot f_1+ r_2+f_2$. 
My goal is to eliminate the possibility of addition of two polynomials to have an root in $R$. 
edit: all polynomials are defined over polynomial ring $R[x]$ where $R$ is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $p$ is a large prime number.

Question: What is the probability of $f'_3$ to have a root in $R$?

Comment: When dealing with an infinite number of possibilities probability makes sense only when the distribution is specified.

Comment: @Crostul What would your answer be to the above question, though?

Comment: @user13676 I cannot understand your question, so I cannot give you an answer. However, your question seems to be very hard because of the non trivial structure of $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$.

Comment: @Crostul   Now I get your point, I meant the integers in the field, and I've modified the question. Thanks for the hint.